# Run-time error 1004 when trying to change font color on protected sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Below code works as long as the sheet is not protected, but I can't see why it doesn't work when protected.

None of the KeyCells are locked.
The error appears on the following line:
`Range(Target.Address).Font.Color = vbBlack`

The error is "Application-defined or object-defined error"

This is the whole code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Sheets("MISC").Range("C31") = True Then
        Dim KeyCells As Range
        Set KeyCells = Range("C15:EL15,AA22:ED22,W30:DN30,W34:DN34,S41:DZ41,C13:EL13,AA20:ED20,W28:DN28,W32:DN32,S39:DZ39")

        If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
            Dim objRegex As Object
            Dim RegMC As Object
            Dim RegM As Object
            Dim item As Variant
            Dim DirArray As Variant
            Dim DirArray2 As Variant
            Dim DirArr As Variant
            '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            Range(Target.Address).Font.Color = vbBlack
            '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            arr = Sheets("MISC").Range("O4:O145").Value
            lASTrOW = Sheets("MISC").Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).row
            DirArray = Join(Application.Transpose(Sheets("MISC").Range("K4:K" & lASTrOW).Value), "|")

            DirArray2 = Replace(Worksheets("LI").TextBox3.Value, ",", "|")
            DirArr = DirArray & "|" & DirArray2
            '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
            On Error Resume Next
            With objRegex
                .Global = True
                .Pattern = DirArr
                If .test(Range(Target.Address).Value) Then
                    Set RegMC = .Execute(Range(Target.Address).Value)
                    For Each RegM In RegMC
                        If InStr(DirArray2, RegM) Then
                            Range(Target.Address).Characters(RegM.FirstIndex + 1, RegM.Length).Font.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)
                        ElseIf RegM = "COL" Or RegM = "CRT" Then
                            Range(Target.Address).Characters(RegM.FirstIndex + 1, RegM.Length).Font.Color = RGB(0, 176, 240)
                        Else
                            Range(Target.Address).Characters(RegM.FirstIndex + 1, RegM.Length).Font.Color = RGB(247, 150, 70)
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            End With
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why is `Range(Target.Address)` needed? I would think that was just `Target`.

Comment: I tried changing it, but the error persists

Comment: @Cyril, I updated both, but the error persists on the same line

Comment: Allowing cell formatting on protecting the sheet solved the problem. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

A protected sheet is a protected sheet - the user cannot modify anything in locked cells - and this is true also for VBA.

So, when you plan to modify anything with code, you have to use the unprotect-method of the worksheet first, do your modifications and set the protection again (you can omit the password if the sheet in not password protected).

```
Const mySecret = "Blablabla"
With ActiveSheet
    .Unprotect mySecret
    ...
    Target.Font.Color = vbBlack
    ...
    .Protect mySecret
End With
```

There is a way to set the protection on a worksheet that allows the modification via code:

```
ActiveSheet.Protect mySecret, UserInterfaceOnly:=True
```

However, there is a small problem: If you save the Workbook, the `UserInterfaceOnly` will be forgotten - with other words, if you reopen the file, the worksheet is still protected, but now again also against modifications via VBA.

Btw: It was already mentioned, writing `Range(Target.Address)` is unnecessary. It's like pointing to a book in a shelf, going to a catalog to get the place (address) of the book within that shelf and pick the book that is at this place.